# mx.core.mx_internal is not displaying

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am trying to use namespace mx_internal but its not showing in package mx.core.*;
I am just trying to use the below example

```
package com.classs
{
import mx.controls.ToggleButtonBar;
import mx.core.*;

internal namespace mx_internal;


public class Toggle extends mx.controls.ToggleButtonBar
{

    public function Toggle()
    {
        super();
        this.percentWidth=100;

        mx_internal::navItemFactory = new mx.core.navItemFactory(com.classs.Bar);

        return;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
use namespace mx_internal
```

Comment: When i used "use" keyword it shows an error, so i replaced that with internal

Comment: hey, sorry, i don't know how but it started working. Sorry to bother you. If i come across the same error i will surely look for solution an will post here. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: You are welcome. Seems that your ide haven't sdk attached at that moment, because your code tried to define this namespace, although it is defined in mx.core